# I have an array of objects, but I only want to access a single quality of a single object. (in javascript)

Tags: arrays, dictionary, object, filter, foreach

I have the following array of objects, It contains the name of the employee, and his salary. I must create a function that receives that array, the name of the employee, and returns the salary of the employee, multiplied by 12.

This is the object:
var emeployees = [{
name: 'Manuel',
salary: 1000,
},
{
name: 'Flor',
salary: 4000,
},
{
name: 'Maria',
salary: 500,
}
];
this is the function
function anualSalary(employees, name) {
// I dont know how to do this

}

anualSalary(empleados, 'Flor'); => 48000
anualSalary(empleados, 'Manuel;); => 12000

Answer (score 1):

basic JSON manipulation / reading in JavaScript is very easy as you can just address the object keys with `jsonObject.keyName`.
I just use a for loop and iterate over all JSON object in your object array.
In your case the code could look something like this:

```js
var emeployees = [{ name: 'Manuel', salary: 1000, }, { name: 'Flor', salary: 4000, }, { name: 'Maria', salary: 500, }];

function anualSalary(employees, name) {
    for (const employee of employees){
        if (employee.name = name){
            return employee.salary * 12;
        }
    }
}

console.log(anualSalary(emeployees, "Flor"));
```

EDIT:

- Updated snippet to make function signature fit given example

Answer (score 1):

```js
function annualSalary(name) {
    var employee = employees.find((employee) => employee.name === name);
    return employee.salary * 12;
}
```